# Adding Tensors with Offsets

Tags: python, tensorflow

Example,
I have a two dimensional tensor.

```
array = np.array([1,2,3],[1,2,3],[1,2,3])
tensor = tf.constant(array)
```

I would like to calculate the sum of each column in the tensor but require that each row be offset from the others.

```
[0,1,2,3,0,0]
[0,0,1,2,3,0]
[0,0,0,1,2,3]
```

Is it possible to perform this kind of calculation efficiently? I attempted calculating the sum on a sparse representation with `SparseTensor` and `tf.sparse_reduce_sum` but found it computationally inefficient for my data size.

Comment: hm....that could be easier if `tf.diag_part` supported `offset` parameter like `numpy.diagonal`

Answer (score 1):

You can build the shifted sum graph by hand:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

array1 = np.array([[1., 2., 3.],
                  [1., 2., 3.],
                  [1., 2., 3.]], dtype=np.float32)
tensor1 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(array1))

array2 = np.array([[1., 2., 3., 4.],
                  [1., 2., 3., 4.],
                  [1., 2., 3., 4.],
                  [1., 2., 3., 4.]], dtype=np.float32)
tensor2 = tf.Variable(tf.constant(array2))

def shifted_sum(tensor):
  def shifted_sum_one_column(i):
    s = tf.constant(0., dtype=tf.float32)
    for j in range(tensor.get_shape()[0]):
      if 0 <= i - (j + 1) < tensor.get_shape()[1]:
        s += tensor[tf.constant(j, dtype=tf.int32),
                    tf.constant(i - (j + 1), dtype=tf.int32)]
    return s

  result = []

  for i in range(tensor.get_shape()[1] + tensor.get_shape()[0]):
    result.append(shifted_sum_one_column(i))

  result = tf.stack(result)
  return result

shifted_tensor_1 = shifted_sum(tensor1)
shifted_tensor_2 = shifted_sum(tensor2)

with tf.Session() as sess:
  sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
  print(sess.run(shifted_tensor_1))
  print(sess.run(shifted_tensor_2))
```

The tensor can also be a placeholder but the shape must be known beforehand.